# How to deploy my spray API into production?

Tags: scala, akka, spray

I'm thinking about how should be the process to deploy my already locally tested rest api to the cloud, lets say an infrastructure as a service (not a platform as a service such as Heroku) like amazon.

I have my local envorinment set up with sbt up and running but my question is How should I deploy this in a production environment?

Is it sane to define a process in which the devops pulls the most recent changes from the git repo and then simply executes sbt run?

I want to know how does the teams that uses scala+spray+sbt deploys their apis to a production environment.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The heart of our services is scala + akka + spray + mongo. So we are using GitHub for version control. After merging checked PRs to the master branch, Jenkins automaticaly tests'n'builds project. If all tests were successful then Jenking runs a couple of scripts:

1. Increment project version (currently written in shell, but will be changed to sbt)
2. Run assembly task with [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)
3. Run deploy script (written in Python with Fabric) wich deploys our jar to EC2

Basicaly on the thrid step you have a couple of choices:

**Make a runnable jar using IO/Spray boot file:**

```
object Boot extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("ServiceName")
  val log = system.log
  val service = system.actorOf(Props[Service], name="serviceActor")
  IO(Http) ! Http.Bind(service, interface = host, port = port)
}
```

**Make a runnable jar as Akka's microkernel:**

In this case you should extend Bootable trait and override `startup` and `shutdown` methods:

```
class Kernel extends Bootable {
  // many lines of code
  def startup() {
    scheduler.start()
    SomeActorSystem.startup()
  }

  def shutdown() {
    scheduler.shutdown()
    SomeActorSystem.shutdown()
    system.shutdown()
  }
}
```

**Using a TypeSafe startscript:**

Can't show an example, but it has a good intro on [github](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-start-script) =)

We are using all of this way in different cases.

Comment: May you elaborate on how you're handling graceful shutdown for sprays services at production? I can create a question.

Comment: @dmitry We don't have any need to support long-live connections, but in general you can use akka cluster with persistence + actors lifecycle (actor hooks). On the other hand Spray is also build on top of Akka, so you can build your own module to gracefully shutdown a server with `Unbind` message to the listener actor. `Unbind` takes a graceful shutdown time, then send it to the listener and wait for Terminated, then you can `shutdown` you service.

Comment: Just an update to the above. Looks like TypeSafe is deprecating startscript to be replaced by sbt-native-packager https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager

Answer (score 2):

You should build a jar with the plugin [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly)

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.9.0")
```

Then you can run the jar in production with java -jar

If you give version number to your project, this is a rather classic process.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

*Never went to PRO with spray-akka. Only pet projects. My suggestions here should be taken as inspiration. I know some of the options I present are costly in terms of maintenance or prone to errors.*

**Packaging**

I only used maven-shade-plugin (no experience with sbt) but I guess there's a similar solution.

**Packaging Issues**

There's few issues with this approach though. Akka and many of the spray modules use the references.conf and application.conf convention. When assembly/shading all your dependencies the resources (since they are named the same) may overwrite and you'd be unable to start the application.

The quick and dirty solution I found was to copy/paste the application and ref.conf of the dependencies into one controlled by me.