# How to package spray.io application, so it will only depend on java?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, spray

Is there a way to create something like a dist package (like in play framework) so I could run my spray server app (http://spray.io/) with only Java installed on my server?

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/q/17396796/298389

Comment: So it seems I could do that with sbt-assembly. However, would it be enough to create a package using 'dist' sbt command?

Comment: you also need to create an entry point, as it shown in the top answer